# jQuery .on() method doesn't work with append dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

jQuery .on() method works well with 'click' event, but it doesn't work with 'load'.

How to add class to new dom  after ajax load? I can't edit $('.nav a') click function(),it in another js file, Here's my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
 $('.nav a').click(function(){
  var nav  = $(this).attr('href').replace('#',''); 
  $.post(nav + ".html",function(result){
   $('.content').append(result); //result: <li> A </li> <li> B </li>
  });
  return false;
  });

  // it works
 $('body').on('click', 'li', function() {
  $(this).addClass('red');
 })

  // doesn't work 
  $('body').on('load', 'li', function() {
  $(this).addClass('red');
  })

})
</script>
<style>.red{color:red} </style>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#about">about</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="content"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What should `$('body').on('load','li',function(){` do? What is your task exactly?

Comment: I need load some dom append to body via ajax, then add class to li once html ready

Comment: Ok but there's no ajax call in the code you posted...

Answer (score 0):

add `$('.content').find('li').addClass('red')` after `$('.content').append(result);` Following code snippets may help you.

```js
var nav = $('#nav');
var result = `<li> A </li> <li> B </li>`;
$('#myBtn').click(function() {
  nav.append(result);
    nav.find('li').addClass('red');
});
```

```css
.red{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="myBtn">
  Attach DOM
</button>
<ul id="nav">

</ul>
```